# Oracle Data Pump (Exclude and Metadata)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump

I need to perform a datapump in 11.2 and want to exclude some tables but include the metadata only..

i.e. export a schema, but exclude about 12 tables (which is easy enough), but then I need to just export metadata from about 20 tables. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the `CONTENT` parameter. It accepts 3 values:

- `ALL`
- `DATA_ONLY`
- `METADATA_ONLY` -- which is what you're looking for

More info in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL838).